"PySpark Code Execution Issue: Py4JJavaError Message"
I encounter the following error when attempting to execute this simple code within Jupyter:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TestPySpark").getOrCreate()

data = [("Alice", 1), ("Bob", 2), ("Carol", 3)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Name", "Value"])

df.show()

Error Message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 13
     10 df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Name", "Value"])
     12 # نمایش اطلاعات DataFrame
---> 13 df.show()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:945, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    885 def show(self, n: int = 20, truncate: Union[bool, int] = True, vertical: bool = False) -> None:
    886     """Prints the first ``n`` rows to the console.
    887 
    888     .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
   (...)
    943     name | Bob
    944     """
--> 945     print(self._show_string(n, truncate, vertical))

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:963, in DataFrame._show_string(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    957     raise PySparkTypeError(
    958         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
    959         message_parameters={"arg_name": "vertical", "arg_type": type(vertical).__name__},
    960     )
    962 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 963     return self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical)
    964 else:
    965     try:

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\pyspark\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o69.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (DESKTOP-HBH6S97 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedAccept(NioSocketImpl.java:701)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.accept(NioSocketImpl.java:745)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:695)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.platformImplAccept(ServerSocket.java:660)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:636)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:582)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:541)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:190)
    ... 32 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2856)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2792)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3060)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:530)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:483)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:4332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:3314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:4320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:3314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:315)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedAccept(NioSocketImpl.java:701)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.accept(NioSocketImpl.java:745)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:695)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.platformImplAccept(ServerSocket.java:660)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:636)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:582)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:541)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:190)
    ... 32 more

This error persists despite trying several troubleshooting steps such as reinstalling packages, testing different versions of Python, Java, and Spark, and checking access permissions like firewall settings and antivirus software. Any insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated
